Cannot import .sql file created on a PC into PostgreSQL on my Mac. Converted to LF on VSC but I keep getting syntax error on the COPY query line
Never really worked with PostgreSQL before and I but cannot find anything online and chatGPT is now going in circles. Other team members work on PSc, I work on Mac. Set up psql, set up the db, migrated tables from the project, and then I wanted to import the  db.sql file everyone is using.
------ ** PROBLEM SECTION ON IMPORT (pgAdmin) ** ------
COPY table (id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, created_at, updated_at)
FROM stdin;
2 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 value_6 value_7 value_8
------ ** I GET THIS ** ------
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 3133: 2 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 value_6 value_7...
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 95333
------ ** I TRIED THIS ** ------
Switched file to LF on VSC, confirmed values were separated by a tab space, and that COPY section was terminated by a "." . Got same error
Tried adding "WITH (NULL '\N')" after "FROM stdin". Got same error for that spot, regardless of what character is on there.
Tried dos2unix db.sql on the terminal. Got this back:
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1F found at line 11489
dos2unix: Skipping binary file db.sql
Searched [0x1F] and it is a lot of what looks like spaces. Not sure if it is non-printable characters or what, but the file has over 40,000 lines of code so I cannot just eliminate something everywhere without knowing if it will have consequences.
The more experienced devvers say it is a Mac issue. Either way I haven't been able to fix this with or without help.

.sql is just the extension someone used and we have no idea how this file was created. My best bett is pg_dump, in archive format. Try pg_restore to restore this file into your database, not a GUI tool like pgAdmin. (however, in the past pgAdmin did support files like this, using pg_restore)

I think it was indeed pg_dump, but I'm not sure. I was avoiding psql command line because it gave me so much grief on installation. Even so, that is what I ended up using: psql -U postgres -d project_name  -f /Users/Erika/Documents/Project_Folder/db.sql

Thanks for your answer, though @FrankHeikens!
